# How to include the primary key value of the selected data base on my stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I adapted a script originally written by [Narayana Vyas Kondreddi in 2002](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm). I changed the where clause to check text/ntext fields as well, by using patindex rather than like. I also changed the results table slightly. Unreasonably, I changed variable names, and aligned as I prefer (no disrespect to Mr. Kondretti). The user may want to change the data types searched. I used a global table to allow querying mid-processing, but a permanent table might be a smarter way to go.

```
/* original script by Narayana Vyas Kondreddi, 2002 */
/* adapted by Oliver Holloway, 2009 */

/* these lines can be replaced by use of input parameter for a proc */
declare @search_string varchar(1000);
set @search_string = 'what.you.are.searching.for';

/* create results table */
create table ##string_locations (
  table_name varchar(1000),
  field_name varchar(1000),
  field_value varchar(8000)
)
;
/* special settings */
set nocount on
;
/* declare variables */
declare
  @table_name varchar(1000),
  @field_name varchar(1000)
;
/* variable settings */
set @table_name = ''
;
set @search_string = QUOTENAME('%' + @search_string + '%','''')
;
/* for each table */
while @table_name is not null
begin

  set @field_name = ''
  set @table_name = (
    select MIN(QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name))
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    where 
      table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and
      QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name) > @table_name and
      OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
  )

  /* for each string-ish field */
  while (@table_name is not null) and (@field_name is not null)
  begin
    set @field_name = (
      select MIN(QUOTENAME(column_name))
      from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      where 
        table_schema    = PARSENAME(@table_name, 2) and
        table_name  = PARSENAME(@table_name, 1) and
        data_type in ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext') and
        QUOTENAME(column_name) > @field_name
    )

    /* search that field for the string supplied */
    if @field_name is not null
    begin
      insert into ##string_locations
      exec(
        'select ''' + @table_name + ''',''' + @field_name + ''',' + @field_name + 
        'from ' + @table_name + ' (nolock) ' +
        'where patindex(' + @search_string + ',' + @field_name + ') > 0'  /* patindex works with char & text */
      )
    end
    ;
  end
  ;
end
;

/* return results */
select table_name, field_name, field_value from ##string_locations (nolock)
;
/* drop temp table */
--drop table ##string_locations
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your result table definition to this :

```
create table ##string_locations (
        table_name varchar(1000),
        field_name varchar(1000),
        field_value varchar(8000),
        id_field_name varchar(max),
        id int
     )
```

Declare these variables

```
@id_field_name varchar(max),
@qry varchar(max)
```

Include this statement right above this comment '/* search that field for the string supplied */'

```
SELECT @id_field_name = (SELECT top 1 QUOTENAME(keys.COLUMN_NAME) 
                                  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE keys
                                 WHERE keys.TABLE_NAME =PARSENAME(@table_name, 1)
                                   and keys.TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@table_name, 2)
                                   and OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1)
```

Modify your insert statement to this :

```
 SELECT @qry = 'select ''' + @table_name + ''',''' + @field_name + ''',''' + @field_name + ''',''' + ISNULL(@id_field_name, '') + ''',' + ISNULL(@id_field_name, 'NULL') + 
    ' from ' + @table_name + ' (nolock) ' +
    'where patindex(' + @search_string + ',' + @field_name + ') > 0';
 insert into ##string_locations(table_name, 
                                field_name, 
                                field_value, 
                                id_field_name, 
                                id)
  exec(
    @qry  /* patindex works with char & text */
  )
```

Then modify your result display :

```
select * from ##string_locations;
```

The full code is :

```
 /* original script by Narayana Vyas Kondreddi, 2002 */
/* adapted by Oliver Holloway, 2009 */

 /* these lines can be replaced by use of input parameter for a proc */
 declare @search_string varchar(1000);
 set @search_string = 'Alpha';

/* create results table */
drop table ##string_locations;
create table ##string_locations (
table_name varchar(1000),
field_name varchar(1000),
field_value varchar(8000),
id_field_name varchar(max),
id int
)
;
/* special settings */
set nocount on
;
/* declare variables */
declare
@table_name varchar(1000),
@field_name varchar(1000),
@id_field_name varchar(max),
@qry varchar(max)
;
/* variable settings */
set @table_name = ''
;
set @search_string = QUOTENAME('%' + @search_string + '%','''')
;
/* for each table */
while @table_name is not null
begin

set @field_name = ''
set @table_name = (
select MIN(QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name))
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where 
  table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and
  QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name) > @table_name and
  OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(table_schema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(table_name)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
)

/* for each string-ish field */
while (@table_name is not null) and (@field_name is not null)
begin
SELECT @field_name =  MIN(QUOTENAME(cols.column_name))

  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
  where 
    cols.table_schema    = PARSENAME(@table_name, 2) and
    cols.table_name  = PARSENAME(@table_name, 1) and
    cols.data_type in ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'text', 'ntext') and
    QUOTENAME(cols.column_name) > @field_name

SELECT @id_field_name = (SELECT top 1 QUOTENAME(keys.COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE keys
                                WHERE keys.TABLE_NAME =PARSENAME(@table_name, 1)
                                  and keys.TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@table_name, 2)
                                and OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1)


/* search that field for the string supplied */
if @field_name is not null
begin
  SELECT @qry = 'select ''' + @table_name + ''',''' + @field_name + ''',''' + @field_name + ''',''' + ISNULL(@id_field_name, 'NULL') + ''',' + ISNULL(@id_field_name, 'NULL') + 
    ' from ' + @table_name + ' (nolock) ' +
    'where patindex(' + @search_string + ',' + @field_name + ') > 0';

  insert into ##string_locations(table_name, field_name, field_value, id_field_name, id)
  exec(
    @qry
  )
end
;
end
;
end
;

select * from ##string_locations;


;
```

Comment: I will definitely try that. Will update you if I encounter some problem.Thank you

Comment: When I add the query that you gave  the result output for isPrimaryKey is No and for PKName Null

Comment: It will be 'No' for columns which are not in the primary key constraints of the DB. For example, if the searched string is in the column 'CustName' of  a table 'Customer' and if 'CustName is included in the primary key constraint of 'CustName', then you will see 'Yes' and PK constraint names in the result set.

Comment: Is if possible that the output result would be the value or id of specific row. For example table Project and the search string "project" i want to show the ProjectID / ID of that row is that possible on the script?

Comment: Sample Result that I want to achieve:  
table_name:[dbo].[ProjectProposals] field_name:[ProjectDescription]       field_value : Sencha Project         ID:23

Comment: Thank you so much will try that approach now.

Comment: May you please send me the full script including your updated changes. Because when I'm trying to add it to my script the result for id_field_name = ' and id = 0.

Comment: That was because the table where the field exists doesn't have a primary key. I have edited the code. This code's result set would have an empty id_field_name and a null id for such tables.

Comment: Here's the structure of my basic database. I have a PK which is set to auto increment. [link] http://i7.photobucket.com/albums/y283/eugene0014/DBStructure_zpsmo9nvb62.png

Comment: Can you please attach here the full script just like my post. and i will check the changes using beyond compare. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

> Sample Result that I want to achieve:
>   table_name  [ProjectDescription]
>   field_name     [dbo].[ProjectProposals]
>   field_value  Sencha Project
>   ID  23